# How to call twitter library after login with firebase twitter oauth

Tags: firebase

I'm developing a html5/javascript web app.
I can log the user with firebase twitter oauth successfully.
But now, after login, how can I call safety twitter rest and streaming api?

Comment: Firebase auth !== Twitter auth. See also: [twitter.accessToken and twitter.accessTokenSecret](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/twitter.html) in the Firebase auth docs. I believe you use those to authenticate against the Twitter API, although they are short lived and can't be refreshed.

Comment: I’m doing the same thing as well. You can use twitter lib to do the rest and streaming stuff. And yes, you should do this on server side because of CORS in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase only utilizes Twitter insofar as using the login API for authentication. If you want to actually use the Twitter REST API, I recommend checking  out their [public documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public).

Comment: Ok, so to call twitter api I have to reauthenticate to twitter api and I have to do it in server side?